# HTML - Background size contain gives too small image

Tags: html, image, background-size

I use:

```
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("http://www.drought-smart-plants.com/images/two-succulents-flowering-21457588.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
</style>
```

in an attempt to have a background image that always stretches to show the whole image but as I test this, the image turns to be way to small... What is the matter of this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to give the body a height.

```css
html, body {
     height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url("http://www.drought-smart-plants.com/images/two-succulents-flowering-21457588.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Or you can add a "background div".

```css
#bkg {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  
  background-image: url("http://www.drought-smart-plants.com/images/two-succulents-flowering-21457588.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="bkg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show the full resolution of the image by taking out `background-size:contain`

[Results](http://jsfiddle.net/waeyL2xb/)

Comment: The downside with this is it "cuts" the image when the viewport is smaller than the image.